# How to add authentication using JWT on a React app?

Tags: reactjs, express, authentication, react-router, jwt

I'm working on a web app with React. I am using React Router with it. I would like to add the ability to access to some protected pages with authentication. I have a back-end server running with Express. I have looked for information to implement that but it is still confusing to me.

I have look for redirection on [this page](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow). On this page, a fake authentication system is simulated to explain the redirection system. I would like to replace it. I have read about JWT in order to deal with that but I do not really understand how to use it...

Can I have some tips for that? I would like to have an endpoint like /login on my express server which will serve, if it is done that way, a token when the login and the passwords are correct. And I would like to use this token for handling access to restricted pages.

Thanks!

Comment: There's a few tutorials about using JWT with React apps. Like this one that even has the code for an express backend part: https://medium.com/@rajaraodv/securing-react-redux-apps-with-jwt-tokens-fcfe81356ea0 - Essentially, when they log in you provide them with a JWT (which is stored in the browser) and then for the routes you want to protect, you use middleware that checks if their request has that token (and that it's a valid token). Examples of all of this can be found in the tute I linked above and others.

Comment: I hope about checking firebase? I use it and like it... :)

Comment: I have followed your tutorial for getting an endpoint that gives me token when right credentials are sent. How Can I use or with React now (I am not using redux)? Firebase seems cool but I'd like to implement myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get the authentification working through this link https://hptechblogs.com/using-json-web-token-react/
and https://medium.com/@rajaraodv/securing-react-redux-apps-with-jwt-tokens-fcfe81356ea0 for server side.

For the first link, you have to change some lines. When you implement handleFormSubmit(), do not forget to call it with onClick on the submit button and remove "type=submit".
In AuthService, do not forget to return a Promise.Reject() in login, when there is an error.
With those changes, it had worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

You can add onEnter in your router.onEnter property allows you to inspect the requested route and send the user to a different route based on parameters you define.

You can use it like this.

```
function requireAuth(nextState, replace) {
  if (!loggedIn()) {
    replace({
      pathname: '/login'
    })
  }
}

function routes() {
  return (
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="login" component={Login} />
      <Route path="logout" component={Logout} />
      <Route path="checkout" component={Checkout} onEnter={requireAuth} />
    </Route>
  );
}
```